# Sorting rows sql

Tags: sql, sorting

I have a question that seems to be 'simple' solution .. but is still pounding me on the head here, I have a table with the rows

```
columns: x, y   
1 , 3 
3 , 8 
1 , 2 
3 , 7
```

then, sometimes, the ordering will be right, knowing that 'all the results in column X' are different, just that .. it is the same, I want to use the column Y as sort criteria, it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM table
ORDER BY x, y;
```

That sorts by `x` first, using `y` as the tie-breaker.

Answer (score 6):

```
select x, y
from [your table]
order by x, y
```

This is defaulting in ascending order.  You can specify

```
....
order by x, y desc
```

To order `y` in descending order.

The lesson here is that you sort by multiple fields in a table, you just need to separate the column names by a comma in your query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order by` to specify several fields separated with comma (`,`).

```
select x, y from table
order by x, y
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT x, y FROM table_name ORDER BY x, y
```

This will order by `X` and then by `Y` (if `X` is the same for two rows)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted the query you're using.  Are you using 'ORDER BY' at all?

SELECT x,y FROM coordinates ORDER BY x,y;

This would sort first by X then by Y values.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from <tablename>
 order by x, y
```

Answer (score 0):

This would sort the rows by values in col y (ascending):

```
SELECT x, y FROM table order by y
```